# Extracting assembly from SQL Server database after backup

Tags: .net, sql-server, dll, assemblies, reflector

I have following situation.

I got backup database file - *.bak. I restored it locally and everything works fine except I I'm unable to get my hands on the .dll assemblies. Obviously I can't look up the local paths to the files on the server as - after restoring - the file system is different.

The general plan was to *somehow* extract loaded .dll files and then use reflector to update the code in visual studio - this is, however, no longer the case. Is it possible or do I have to somehow get original dllls?

Thanks

Comment: The binary versions are all stored inside the database not on the file system. Look at the various views beginning `sys.assembly_`. The [SQL Browser addin](http://www.reflector.net/add-ins/)  is probably what you need.

Comment: I know - that's why I'm asking. So the "content" is effectively the whole file in binary format?

Answer (score 2):

`content` column in [`sys.assembly_files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175085.aspx)

Comment: Ah, the content is actually the whole file; I never really checked it which suggests that my question was posted prematurely.

Comment: Yes, and there could be more entries for a single assembly *if* you added additional files (eg. .pdb for debugging) via `ALTER ASSEMBLY ... ADD FILE ...`. As the link says, `The file ID numbered 1 represents the assembly DLL.`

Comment: Never really debugged assemblies. I guess it's time to start