# SQL Server CLR backup Assembly causes MVID error

Tags: sql-server, clr, .net-assembly

I want to create a 'rollback' or backup script for a CLR assembly that is already in a database, i.e., usually with other types of object, I can script it out with SSMS and then rerun the script with a different object name to create a backup. However with CLR types I get this error

> Msg 6285, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because the source assembly is, according to MVID, identical to an assembly that is already registered under the name "MYDB.CLRBackup".

Example script being

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [MYDB.CLRBackup]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF.....;
```

What are people doing to create backup copies of CLR objects for 'rollback' versions or copies?

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: Overall as I think this CLR use DLL files, which you can easily save... and as I guess you trying create another Assembly to same file, which sql not let you do this.

Comment: Ah ok sure, so when you say 'easily save', sure if you have the original assembly, but what if its already in the DB, how do you save it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what if you just back up this table `sys.assembly_files`.

Column `content` contains content of file.

Answer found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14198690/1692632